# how to update configuration for one of the configuration file inside POD file systems

Tags: bash, kubernetes, exec

I am able to exec to a POD and inside POD one of the configuration I need to update highlighted below, how I can update this,

Like I need to change port from 8080 to 8090

[image]

Comment: You could `kubectl cp` that PNG file into an individual Pod, but most applications can't read PNG files, what configuration they do read is typically only read on startup, you'd only affect one replica of a Deployment that way, and any change would be lost as soon as the Pod is deleted (not necessarily under your control).  You mention `kubectl exec` in the question and that has basically the same problems.

Comment: Not my downvote. Please replace image with its text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things should be understood first... Do you use a Helm Chart? If yes, try to see if inside the values.yaml it's possible to change that parameter.

If not, create a ConfigMap with the values ​​you want, in this case you can simply copy the configuration you find in the Pod and bring it back with the correct parameters.

Then mount the ConfigMap in the path where the original file is.

This will overwrite the old file with your correct ConfigMap.

Check it out here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/